# Win10 unremovable keyboard layout

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I can't remove a keyboard layout and it's really annoying.

[image]

After reading and diggind the web looking for the solution i didnt find the result. The language setting in the control panel wouldn't display that layout

[image]

[image]

There was only a USA layout. I need to remove the UK layout.

P.S. sorry for foreign language.

Answer (score 2):

Add another keyboard layout for the mean time. Let's say you have the following layout.

[RUSSIAN (RUSSIAN, whatsoever the dialect/keyboard layout is)]
[ENGLISH (US)]
[ENGLISH (UK)]

if the UK is default. Make it not the default keyboard layout / input language, you can remove then the UK keyboard layout.

PS: It's still windows, just skinned as macOS like.

First, if the ENG UK is default. Don't default it
[image]

After changing it, look for English UK in the list, then remove.
[image]

IT WORKS FOR ME. GIVE IT A TRY.
[image]

Comment: I cant find the text services and input languages dialogue box. Maybe it's just a win7 thing

Comment: There is also in windows 10. Thought i think not present atleast with the creators update. But you can change default in its pc settigs app. Im sure you've been there because youve manage to remove other layouts. Try it again but this time, check if uk english is not default, for you to be able to remove it

Answer (score 1):

## Removing the Substitute keyboard

- Open the Registry Editor
- Navigate to `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard Layout\Substitutes` (if empty, check `Computer\HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Substitutes`)
- Find a key with a mapping between the **correct** language to the **incorrect** language id.
- Remove the key
- **Restart** your machine.

An FYI:

> The Substitutes subkey allows to assign alternative keyboard layouts preferred by the user.
> This key is empty unless the user has selected a substitute keyboard layout

### Unable to use previous answer

BTW, I couldn't use [@jimwel-anobong answer](https://superuser.com/a/1202497/168976) since the `Text Services and Input Languages` window in latest Windows 10 versions is missing the `General` tab:[image: Text Services and Input Languages without general tab]

if you still need this window, you can open it by using the command line `Rundll32 Shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL input.dll,,{C07337D3-DB2C-4D0B-9A93-B722A6C106E2}`